# Net Core for Ubuntu 16.04 i386

Tags: .net, ubuntu

I am trying to install .Net Core 1.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 i386

I am watching only has verswion for amd64 when I install obviousdlly binary file is not compatible.

How can I install Net Core in Ubuntu i386?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across to this same problem when I tried to make my old sitting Pentium III machine as a .net core webapi host.

As explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/), there is no official plan for i386 distribution. When asked, .net team always responded "ARM is next".

So, the official answer to your question is **no, you can't install for now**.

Comment: I am using now monoDevelop